# Boundary conditions for the Dirac spinor

Tags: field-theory, boundary-conditions, dirac-equation

I know how to solve the Dirac equation, because I have learnt it from Peskin and Schroeder. But I realized that no constants or boundary conditions appear in the solution to the Dirac eq., as it is a first order differential equation. I can't figure it out, and I have no clue. My guess is that P&S just skipped that part for simplicity. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In P&S they used the ansatz of $\psi(x) = \mathcal{u} e^{-ip \cdot x}$, i.e. a plane wave solution. This then leads to constraints on $\mathcal{u}$ (by substituting the ansatz in the Dirac equation). Solving for these constraints shows that $\mathcal{u}$ depends continuously on 3 momentum $\vec{p}$ and discretely on an index $s$ taking values $s \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

This is not the most general (classical) solution of the Dirac equation, the most general solution is a linear combination of all such plane wave solutions, i.e.

$$\psi (x) = \sum_s \int d^3p A^s_{\vec{p}} \space\mathcal{u}^s_{\vec p}e^{-ip \cdot x}$$ where the $A^s_{\vec{p}} $ are *c-numbers*. The initial conditions fix the values of these c- numbers, $A^s_{\vec{p}} $.

This isn't explored is because we are more interested in field operator expansion in canonical quantization.

Comment: I understand it now. What would the boundary condition look like? Would the most general solution be of use for anything?